# R Studio keeps 'hanging' when trying to establish an Oracle Database connection

Tags: r, database, oracle, rstudio, dbi

I'm working a little side project on R Studio and I'm trying to import data from an Oracle database. The problem is, whenever I try to establish the connection using the **DBI::dbConnect** command, it just 'hangs'. It won't continue to the next command on my R Studio script. I've added a timeout to the dbConnect command, but it doesn't help anything. In order to exit, I have to shut down R Studio completely.

I've tested the connection, check the screenshot below, using the 'Connections' tab on R Studio. As you can see, it is able to establish the connection. So that should mean the parameters are set correctly, right? But when I run it on the script, it just keeps 'hanging' on the dbConnect command.

What can I do?

[image: screenshot from R Studio]

Comment: (Tangent: you might want a password longer than three characters ...)

Answer (score 0):

When it connects successfully to the database RStudio loads in connection pane a tree which present all schemas and all tables. It's useful by it can be slow.

Depending on Oracle database I use, it often takes a long time to load this and it's longer when user have low privileges on database (user with only one schema for instance).

I see two ways trying to go further:

- connect with your statement on RGui to see if it works correctly then it's really linked to RStudio's connection pane
- connect with system / admin or a higher level user to check if it's work better with